# How to get the first occurrence ? regex python

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

I have this html tag:

```
x=""" <div>ad</div>  \n\n <div> correct value  </div>  <div> wrong value </div>   """
```

I want to get the `corret value`

so I search for the word `ad` followed by `</div>` then any thing until another `<div>` then get all the values until `</div>`

I use this code:

```
re.findall(r'ad</div>.*<div>(.*)</div>',x,re.S)
```

I use the falg re.S because I want the dot to match new line also. I don't know How much lines there are between the divs. so i use .*  !

I think findall should return `correct value`, but it return  `wrong value`. why ? it search for the last div not the first one ?

Comment: Please read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags#answer-1732454

Comment: @DanielRoseman so I shouldn't user regex to parse html, what you suggest ?

Comment: An HTML parser. BeautifulSoup is a good one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

because what you have is *greedy*

try lazy :

```
re.findall(r'ad</div>.*?<div>(.*?)</div>',x,re.S)
```

In your example `.*` is actually matching everything towards the end and then it sees `<div>`, then your regex back tracks and and startes the matching again, similar is the second scenario,

demo here :

http://regex101.com/r/zY9xA3/1

Comment: @downvoter : your downvote doesnt mean anything unless you add a comment along with it

Comment: thank you for your answer, but what the difference between .*? and .*

Comment: `.*?` will match minimum characters while `.*` will do a maximum match. example `a.*b` will match `aabbcccddb` fully while `a.*?b` will match only upto the first b i.e `aab`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to find a thing between `2` special string , use [`Lookahead and Lookbehind Assertions`](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) :

```
>>> re.findall(r'(?<=\<div\>)[\w ]+(?=\<\/div\>)',x)
['ad', ' correct value  ', ' wrong value ']
>>> re.findall(r'(?<=\<div\>)[\w ]+(?=\<\/div\>)',x)[1].strip()
'correct value'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ad</div>((?!<div>).)*<div>(((?!<\/div>).)*)</div>
```

You can try this well.See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/zY9xA3/3

Comment: it's complicated !!!

Answer (score 0):

Through the tool which was specially used for parsing html files.

```
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> x=""" <div>ad</div>  \n\n <div> correct value  </div>  <div> wrong value </div>   """
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(x)
>>> for i, x in enumerate(soup.find_all('div')):
    if x.string == 'ad':
        count = count + i + 1


>>> count
1
>>> soup.find_all('div')[count].string
' correct value  '
>>> soup.find_all('div')[count].string.strip()
'correct value'
```